# get file from ftp pc and save the same in telnetted pc using python

Tags: ftp, telnet

I am trying to write a `python` script to connect a pc using `telnet` and from that telneted pc I am trying to start a `ftp` connection to other pc. I was able to connect telnet and FTP, but the transferred file was not stored in the telneted pc instead it was stored in the pc in which I executed the script.

Can anyone suggest a way how to save file in the  telnetted pc.

```
        via telnet        via ftp
host pc-------------PC 1-----------PC 2   >
```

I need to get file from pc 2 and need to store in pc1. Now its storing in host pc only.

Comment: Thanks abhi...this script works for me!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If you are using Pexpect try  this piece of code in your script...                                                                                                                                                                                       ss.expect(':')
ss.sendline('username')
ss.expect(':')
ss.sendline("password" + "\n")
time.sleep(30)
print "connected 
ss.expect('$ ')
ss.sendline("ftp ipaddress")
```